# How to get the id value of a button using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with dynamically created Edit buttons.
The ID of the buttons is a string that is appended with **table content id**.

i.e:           `<input id='edit'+id type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />`

How can i get the ID(=edit+id) value of the button using jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to get a reference for the input element. Then, just call

```
reference.attr('id');
```

If it had a class, for example, inputClass, you could do:

```
var reference = $(".inputClass");
```

Here's how I would approach your particular situation. You have:

```
<input id='edit1' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />
<input id='edit2' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />
<input id='edit3' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />
```

I would replace this for:

```
<input id='edit1' type='button' value='Edit' class='inputClass'/>
<input id='edit2' type='button' value='Edit' class='inputClass'/>
<input id='edit3' type='button' value='Edit' class='inputClass'/>
```

Then, anywhere in your page, you write this piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.inputClass').each(function() {
      $(this).click(function(){
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          //Do whatever the edit function should do with the id
      });
   });
});
```

this binds a function for each of the  elements which call your edit function...

Comment: What do you mean by reference?

Comment: Just put an example in the edit! For more, take a look here: http://www.tequilafish.com/2007/12/04/jquery-how-to-get-the-id-of-your-current-object/

Comment: Hey I am new to jquery. I understand the answers, but where i have to put those lines. In the function i called when it clicked? If so, just that one line is enough???

Answer (score 1):

```
 var id = $("td input[type='button']").attr('id');
```

The selector says "The input button within a TD"
or

```
 var id = $("td input[id^='edit']").attr('id');
```

The selector says "The input element with an id starting with 'edit' within a TD"

or you can go the whole way:

```
 var id = $("td input[type='button'][id^='edit']").attr('id');
```

The selector says "The input button with an id starting with 'edit' within a TD"

Comment: Would this work if he has more than one? I believe this is the case... He probably wants to retrieve the id from inside the edit function... right, MaRaVaN?

Comment: @Both: Hey I am new to jquery. I understand the answers, but where i have to put those lines. In the function i called when it clicked? If so, just that one line is enough???