# getElementById() Method JS+BS

Tags: javascript, html

how can i take the parameter(number) on a bootstrap input element when i click on the button??

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class ="col-md-6 input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Larghezza</span>
        <div id="myNumber"> <input type="number" class="form-control" id="focusedInput" placeholder="Inserisci qui..." > </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default">Calcola</button>
```

my js code... Then i use the number for some math operation

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
```

Comment: try using focusedInput as your id - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586325/how-to-get-the-id-value-of-a-button-using-jquery - that's jquery but you get the idea, you have to reference the input element, not its container

Answer (score 0):

You are reading `value` property of `div` element while it is a property of the `input`.

Use `id` of `input` and it will work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("focusedInput").value;
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class ="col-md-6 input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon">Larghezza</span>
     <div id="myNumber">
         <input type="number" class="form-control" id="focusedInput" placeholder="Inserisci qui..." >
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default">Calcola</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("focusedInput").value;
```

You need to reference the input element, not its container.